# EasyMotion -- wildcard character

Tags: vim

When using Easymotion, I use 2 characters about 90% of the time and I have it mapped to `s`, so I will type in something like `re`:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to use a wildcard character? For example, something like `r*` or `*e`? I know there is a **second** command in Easymotion to search for one character only, but I only want to use a single shortcut of `s` for everything. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep just enter 1 character and then hit enter. so to search `r*` just enter `r<cr>`

Comment: great, thank you. Is there a way to do a mapping that `*` goes to `<CR>` when in the specific "Search for 2 characters: " dialogue?